# Calculating the period of time from last app termination to the next launch in seconds

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsdate, nsuserdefaults

I need to know how much time elapsed from the moment the app was terminated to the time the app was launched again. I guess you'd have to store the startDate by saving it in the appDelegate when appIsTerminated. Then you'd have to access that value in appDidLaunch, also in appDelegate and then calculate the difference between those times. I need the difference in seconds and I want to use the difference in my viewController. How do I do this in swift 3, Xcode 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right, it's the **simplest** solution.

```
public func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ application: UIApplication){

    UserDefaults.standard.set(Date(), forKey: "latestLaunchDate")
    // your code
    return true
}


public func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
     UserDefaults.standard.set(Date(), forKey: "latestTerminationDate")
     //just to ensure that it is saved
     UserDefaults.standard.syncronize()
}
```

And then in your ViewController

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {

    func method() {
         if let launchDate = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey:  "latestLaunchDate") as? Date,
            let terminationDate = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "latestTerminationDate") as? Date
         {
             // your duration
             let terminationDuration = launchDate.timeIntervalSince(terminationDate)
         }
    }
}
```

So in the example above you'll get to the if body only if both dates (launch and termination were set).
And better way is to define some **global constants** for this purpose, so you won't make typo in strings somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

The `Date` class has a `timeIntervalSince` function:

`date2.timeIntervalSince(date1)`

The `TimeInterval` returned is the number of seconds from `date1` to `date2`.

If you want to use it in your view controller, you can save it somewhere like `UserDefaults` and access it from there.